# Access (working) nfs from VLC on Amazon Fire TV

Tags: android, vlc-media-player, nfs

I have successfully set up `/etc/exports` on my host pc

```
/media/film *(ro,no_subtree_check)
```

on the client pc I can

```
mkdir /tmp/film
sudo mount hostpc:/media/film /tmp/film
ls /tmp/film
```

However if I go into VLC on my Amazon Fire TV and try to access this

```
unable to open the MRL 'nfs://hostpc/media/film'
```

How to I set up VLC on Fire to access this?